# Assigning value to DateTimePicker.Value affects other class properties (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a line that assigns a value to my form's Me.dateTimePickerAddStartDate.Value - the value gets assigned properly, but it also affects all of my Me.checkBoxAddXXXXXX.Checked values, assigning them to TRUE. I'm at a loss in understanding why this might happen - am I doing something wrong?

I just added the CType to ensure that it wasn't an explicit/implicit problem.

If I put the last three lines preceding the Me.checkBoxAddXXXXX.Checked assignments, everything works as expected, but I don't want to cover up a problem and find out it shows up some place else unexpectedly - I'd like to solve the root issue.

```
Me.checkBoxAddMonday.Checked = m_Archiving.Time.Monday
Me.checkBoxAddTuesday.Checked = m_Archiving.Time.Tuesday
Me.checkBoxAddWednesday.Checked = m_Archiving.Time.Wednesday
Me.checkBoxAddThursday.Checked = m_Archiving.Time.Thursday
Me.checkBoxAddFriday.Checked = m_Archiving.Time.Friday
Me.checkBoxAddSaturday.Checked = m_Archiving.Time.Saturday
Me.checkBoxAddSunday.Checked = m_Archiving.Time.Sunday
Me.numericUpDownAddOffset.Value = CType(m_Archiving.Time.OffSet, System.Decimal)
Me.dateTimePickerAddStartDate.Value = CType(m_Archiving.Time.StartDate, System.DateTime)
Me.dateTimePickerAddStartTime.Value = CType(m_Archiving.Time.StartTime, System.DateTime)
```

Comment: Does your DateTimePicker have an event handler that is updating the checkboxes?

Comment: Yes, thank you - it's code that I'm maintaining and didn't think to check for the event handlers. Sure enough, the DateTimePicker.ValueChanged event was setting the CheckBoxes. Once I took this into account, it fixed my issue.